# Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found

Tags: python, sqlite, telebot

Помогите исправить ошибку, которая происходит при выполнении `def news`. Сам код:

```
users = sqlite3.connect('users', check_same_thread=False)
users.cursor()
users.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (usersid TEXT)""")
users.commit()
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def welcome(message):
    if not str(message.chat.id) in users.execute("SELECT * FROM users"):
        users.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES (?)", (message.chat.id,))
        users.commit()
@bot.message_handler(commands=['new'])
def news(message):
    for user in users.execute('SELECT * FROM users'):
        bot.send_message(user, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
```

После использования функции `new` получаю ошибку, хотя код и продолжает работать:

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found"
```

UPD: Забыл упомянуть, что id пользователей уже записаны, поэтому юзеры уже начинали диалог с ботом

Comment: Попробуйте сначала отправить сообщение боту

Comment: @Tehnorobot да в этом-то и проблема: айди пользователей есть уже в бд

Comment: Возьмите учебник по SQL и начните с основ, Telegram бот тут не при чём

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался со своей проблемой. Готовый рабочий код + немного дополнил. Надо было указать массив 0:

```
def callback_inline(call):

    users = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    cursor = users.cursor()
    cursor.execute ("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usersid (id TEXT)""")
    users.commit()

    people_id = call.message.chat.id
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM usersid WHERE id = {people_id}")
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        user_id = [call.message.chat.id]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO usersid VALUES(?);", user_id)
        users.commit()
@bot.message_handler(commands=['new'])
def news(message):
    command_sender = message.from_user.id
    if command_sender in admins:
        users = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        cursor = users.cursor()
        for user in cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM usersid"):
            bot.send_message(user[0], message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
            logging.info(f"Новая рассылка: {message.text} by userid: {message.chat.id}")
    else:
        bot.send_message(command_sender, "У тебя нет доступа к этой команды")
```